How to reduce query size in Bigquery?
My table is bigger than 10 TB now. I just want to select distinct filename from table which should be only a few rows. But it still cost more than 500GB everytime. I tried to create a clustered table but it can't update dynamically. Is there a way to do that?

Can you describe how you created the table and how it is populated?   Lets look at a description of the very detailed description of the table.  Creating both partitions and clusters should result in continuous benefit.  There should be no "reclustering" required.  I am thus confused by the phrase "it can't update dynamically" and would like to understand that further.

You can cluster your table with cloud functions on a daily basis (attached is a sample script), or you can also partition your table by date and then create a new table in Dataform for your ad-hoc analysis. This will incrementally add new partition data to your destination table, significantly reducing your costs.

